# Where is the _layouts directory on the server?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I'm editing a file using SharePoint Designer. Where is the folder `url("/_layouts/images/)` stored on the server?

Comment: Welcome! A well written question encourages people to answer it! Please read [our guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116) which I've used to improve your post. You can also read [How to Ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more general guidelines.

Comment: Can you edit files stored in _layouts folder (or one of it's sub folders) using SharePoint Designer? I was always under the impression that you couldn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rob Windsor has said it above, but I wanted to give it "answer" status. While the _layouts folder does indeed live at:

c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12 (SharePoint 2007)

c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14 (SharePoint 2010)

\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15 (SharePoint 2013)

SharePoint Designer *will not* allow you to open those pages.

Comment: Hi Guys Many Thanks for your replies, Marc and Rob thanks for both of your detailed answers, sorry i can only mark one as an answer though :(

Answer (score 8):

The folder "_layouts/images" is a mapped folder in the web server. It maps to the server directory "c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\layouts\images".

With SharePoint Designer you can only edit files stored in the Content Database, which are generally all files that are not in a directory starting with and underscore like "_layouts", "_vti_bin", etc.

If you need to modify Images, you have to upload them to a document library and change the former reference to the "_layouts/images/..." in the file referencing your image (page, master page, page layout, etc.). These files can usually be edited in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

look under 14 hive (if using sp2010) or 12 for sp 2007

Comment: To clarify, this is usually under `c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14` with `layouts\images` taking you to the folder you originally required.

Comment: @Neize Becon: Welcome to SharePoint! While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details. Please edit your post with additional details. See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.