# How can i Locate and modify the corev15.css

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I want to modify the corev15.css file for my team site inside SharePoint 2013, but i am not sure where is this file located inside my windows 2008 r2 server ? can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 4):

You should not modify SharePoint's out of the box style sheet files, they are provided by SharePoint, and used across all sites, if you need to override these styles, you need to create your own style sheet file (css file), place it inside SharePoint, and reference this css file, this way you can overwrite the styles that come by default in SharePoint

Comment: sharepoint's default css styling is bad and heavy handed often the only way to use your own styling without editing theirs is to make even MORE heavy handed references. For instance Sharepoints Corev15.css styles their input buttons with input[type=submit] which steps on bootstraps button styling. So the option is to either edit Sharepoints bad css or manually edit the hundreds of references to the .btn class in bootstraps css.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answers on [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/where-is-the-layouts-directory-on-the-server) about the location of the **_layouts** folder (and it's where *corev15.css* is located), you can access this **folder** in:

c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\

Then in the **web server extensions** folder search for "LAYOUTS", now depending on the path where your *css file* is located (for example: .../_layouts/**15**/1036/styles/corev15.css) you open its **_layouts** folder, this is it for our example:

[image]

After you open the **folder**, you follow again what's in *corev15.css* link and you find your *css file* (like in this picture):

[image]