# Changing the title of the page while creating a new sub site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to change the page title, the one which we see when we create a new `sub site`.

[image]

Is there any OOTB way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to modify the following file

```
/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx
```

As this file contains in the `_layouts` directory, so you can not modify it using SharePoint Designer.

[Where is the _layouts directory on the server?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/where-is-the-layouts-directory-on-the-server)

For SharePoint On-Premise, you will find this file in the following directory in your server. You can try modifying from there.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\15
```

For SharePoint Online We do not have access in the above directory yet.

Comment: then how we do it in office365?

Comment: We can not access this location in office-365

Comment: So, is there no way of doing this in Office-365?

Comment: I think so. Wait and see what other people say

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can be your friend here. You can add the following JS code to the system HTML master page using SharePoint designer and set the title to whatever you like either static or dynamic using SharePoint APIs if that is your requirement.

```
<script>
window.onload= function(){
document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea_ctl00_SkipLink").previousSibling.innerText="New Site";}
</script>
```